# Number of degree $k$ functions

Tags: combinatorics

Given a Boolean function $f:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}$, there is a real multivariate multilinear polynomial that is associated with in through interpolation.

Example: $AND(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n)$ is associated with $\prod_{i=1}^nx_i$.

Degree of Boolean function is total degree of real multivariate multilinear polynomial associated with it.

> How many degree $k$ Boolean functions are there with $n$ variables out of total $2^{2^n}$ functions?

Is there an inductive procedure?

Comment: Can you give another example of these functions $f$? For example, is $OR(x_1,x_2)$ represented by $x_1+x_2$ or $x_1 x_2 + x_1(1-x_2) + x2(1-x_1)$ or $x_1 x_2 + x_1(1-x_2) + x2(1-x_1) + 17x_1(x_1-1)$...?

Comment: $OR(x_1,x_2)=1-(1-x_1)(1-x_2)$.

Comment: Do you consider e.g. $AND(x_1, x_1)$ to be a distinct boolean function from $x_1$, or is one of them the correct associated polynomial and the other incorrect?

Comment: Needs a formal definition of the "real multivariate linear polynomial."  OP has not answered whether AND($x_1, x_1$) and $x_1$ should have distinct polynomials.

Comment: no they are same.